# How to increase the TLS handshake size in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, mtls, schannel

I'm experiencing  connection negotiations failure  while trying to establish two way authentication with .NET clients.

This happens after the remote server increased significantly the list of authorized CA.

While this issue can be easily resolved in any java clients by setting `jdk.tls.maxHandshakeMessageSize` to a higher value, I can't find the same workaround for .NET.

This issue happens with `System.Net.HttpClient`,
`System.Net.Security.SslStream` (.NET Framework 4.7.2) and Internet Explorer 11 .

Comment: .NET (Core) or Framework apps?

Comment: sorry. .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Did you try to play with SCHANNEL registry size? HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Messaging\ and MessageLimitClient?

Comment: i did and it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For API that relies on Windows TLS SCHANNEL, this value can be changed by setting the following DWORD  value on  [registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings#messaging--fragment-parsing).

```
MessageLimitClient : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Messaging
```

Credit for lextm on MSDN.